# can't install Rails on RVM, OS Linux Mint 17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I installed RVM. And then followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm) guide to install Ruby 2.1.3 version d and create GEMSET. after that I tried to install Rails 4 by executing this command:

`gem install rails -v 4.0` but got this error:

```
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
        Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.hi.link" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.hi.link/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.4.gemspec.rz)
```

I researched multiple similair questions but non of them could solve my issue.

Comment: Back the days I tried using RVM as well but it got me nothing but trouble. Maybe you're better off going for rbenv? :)
Other than that, I fear I am not much of a big help to your problem stated in the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to second the use of rbenv over rvm. Rbenv is super simple and I have never had problems with it which I cannot say about rvm. However, this looks like a dns resolution issue. In resolv.conf try setting your dns servers to googles. If that fixes it then follow this to make the changes permanent. https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot

EDIT
well since that didn't work I found this link https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1001,
are you by any chance a comcast customer? If so, this link should help, aparently comcast recently appended some wierd domain for all search path, which would explain why youre getting this issue. I hope this helps.

Comment: In that file I have exactly googles DNS `# This file was written by dns-fix (mintsystem)

# Google DNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8`